# Godaddy Hosting Cron Job Timezone setting

Tags: cron, cpanel

I'm using godaddy hosting and running cron job for codeigniter. That will be running every day at 10am. So in cron tab i tried like this

```
00 10 * * * export TZ=Asia/Dhaka; wget http://www.example.com/function

00 10 * * * TZ=Asia/Dhaka; wget http://www.example.com/function

00 10 * * * export TZ=Asia/Dhaka; /usr/bin/curl "http://www.example.com/function"
```

Always those command executing on others timezone maybe UTC timezone but i need Asia/Dhaka timezone UTC +6:00.

How do i write correct timezone command and where to write it?

Godaddy Cron Tab Look Like this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP, you can figure out both what time is it at your server and in what timezone you're at:

```
echo date('c');
```

It'll output something like:

> 2017-08-15T02:40:09+00:00

Answer (score 2):

The above answers didn't help me, they both gave me the date / time for the domain, but not for cron job. What helped me to determine the cron job schedule is:

1. Take your IP address from cpanel
2. Google where it's located by searching IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
3. Google time in that city / country
4. You have determined your timezone

Comment: I had the exact same issue, and this solution worked perfectly for me. The server showed UTC as timezone in phpinfo(), but the cron timezone turned out to be UTC-7, based on my cronjob tests. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah it's a tricky one, no clear documentation. Glad to help, thanks for voting up

Answer (score 0):

C-Panel cron job manager does not show the current time at the server. When account is set up, it is done on a specific server that resides in a specific timezone.  You need to find out what that timezone is and then set the schedule based on that timezone. You can run a

```
echo date("D M d, g:i A", time())
```

function in `php` to tell you. Then set your schedule.